# Laravel Auth using Third Party Authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am building an application that is using a third party authentication database. I have [created a custom composer package](https://pusher.com/tutorials/publish-laravel-packagist) to "intercept" the  `POST` request to `/login`. Everything is working great - I'm able to get a user object back and save it to my (laravel) database.

I am now at the point where I want to redirect to the home page and do "stuff". I would like to use Laravel's native `Auth` as much as possible if I can.

For example, on the home page I am doing this:

```
$foo = auth()->user()->foo->where('active', 1);
```

No surprise, since I am not using Laravel's native Auth method, `auth()->user()` is returning `null`. Once I have my user created/found in my database, is it possible to tie back into Laravel's `auth()` methods?

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

Reading the documentation, [this looks like the direction I need to go](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) but I'm falling short understanding how to connect/register my custom package (I think)...

**EDIT 2**

I am going to keep updating this as I feel I make any progress in hopes that it will not only help me, but help others get a better picture of what I am trying to accomplish. Ultimately help others who may be trying to do the same.

I have updated my `app/Providers/AuthServiceProviderAuthServiceProvider` as such:

```
use My\Package\MyThirdPartyServiceProvider;


...


Auth::provider('foo', function ($app, array $config) {
        // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...

    return new MyThirdPartyServiceProvider($app->make('foo.connection'));
});
```

I have also updated my `config/auth` file:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'foo',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ]
```

Comment: You will need a class to implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider` interface (either in your package or in your project). That class can be used as an auth driver by configuring it in auth.php and registering it in a service provider.

Comment: Hi PtrTon - could please elaborate a bit? I'm not concerned which project I implement this class. At a high-level, I'm not sure _how_ to implement it. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) suggests implementing a custom user provider. The following steps more or less describe how you'll tackle it in a bit more detail.

1. Create or edit a [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers)
   You can create a new service provider by running

`php artisan make:provider CustomAuthServiceProvider`

2. In the `boot` method of your service provider you'll have to configure our auth provider (which will be implemented in step 4).

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Auth::provider('custom-auth', function ($app, array $config) {
            return new CustomAuthProvider();
        });
    }
```

3. Update your `auth.php` configuration to use the serviceprovider we registered in step 2

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'custom-auth',
    ],
],
```

4. Create the `CustomAuthProvider` class itself and implement the [UserProvider interface](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/UserProvider.html)

```
class CustomAuthProvider implements UserProvider
{
    public function retrieveById($identifier) {
        // Retrieve a user by their unique identifier.
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token) {
        // Retrieve a user by their unique identifier and "remember me" token.
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token) {
        // Update the "remember me" token for the given user in storage.
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) {
        // Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials) {
        // Validate a user against the given credentials.
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me get going in the right direction. Additionally, [this was a great help](https://www.codementor.io/okoroaforchukwuemeka/9-tips-to-set-up-multiple-authentication-in-laravel-ak3gtwjvt)